Could supermassive black holes emit massive particles as part of the Hawking radiation (even if the probability is small)?
Supermassive black holes should have a very low Hawking temperature and therefore would emit very low energetic photons, only when the black hole has radiated most of its mass and becomes small it would radiate more energetic particles like the ones with mass.
(The temperature of the black hole goes like 1/M and it’s that thermal radiation that we would be measuring at that energy. In order to create a particle, you need to put as much energy into the system as the rest mass of that particle, so these facts put together would seem to prevent this. It can technically and does technically emit all (virtual) particles with certain probabilities but only real asymptotic states of particles are produced if the Hawking temperature is equivalent to the rest mass-energy of an object. So even if you can get said probabilities, you'll never get real asymptotic states even if the math checks out since there is not enough mass-energy from the black hole's temperature to generate that particle.)
However, the black hole has a lot of mass, so couldn't there be some kind of fluctuation that statistically gives you a very small (but non zero) probability that a big "chunk" of mass could be lost to form massive particles, even if the event horizon temperature is much lower (similarly to how water evaporates at room temperature, albeit very slowly, due to water particles randomly gaining enough kinetic energy to escape the liquid)?

@ConnorBehan No, I think it does not answer. This question specifically targets if maybe a little larger particles could be ejected due to quantum randomness, with a small probability. The answers there do not cover this topic directly.

@peterh I agree

The answer is yes.

@Ghoster could you elaborate more on that?

A black hole of any mass emits massless particles of arbitrarily high energy with some non-zero probability. Why do you think it would have trouble emitting massive particles, just because some of their energy is mass-energy? The probability of high-energy ($E \gg kT$) emission is exponentially small but not zero. There is never a hard cutoff.

@Ghoster There is never a hard cutoff There is, since black hole cannot emit a particle with an energy larger than its mass (times $c^2$).

@A.V.S. but this would mean that black holes with very low masses would not be able to radiate massive particles, but we expect the contrary (little black holes would evapprate rapidly into relatively high energy particles like those with mass)

@vengaq this would mean that black holes with very low masses would not be able to radiate massive particles That's not a problem since minimal mass of a black hole is expected to be of order of Planck mass, and there are a lot of particles with smaller masses.

@Ghoster considering A.V.S. point, is your argument altered? Or does it stay the same?

Other than not being able to radiate particles with more mass than the black hole mass, it stays the same. A.V.S. corrected only my assertion of no hard cutoff.
